# Problem with variable scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, local-variables, scopes

Ok I am definitely puzzled, why this is not returning 6 in textarea. It doesn't return anything. 
I figured that it has something to do with js scopes, but i cant figure it out.

```
<body>

    <script language="Javascript">
    var broj = 5;  

    function Inci(){
    var broj++;
    document.frmMain.VrsteHolder.value = broj;
    }

    </script>

    <form name="frmMain" method="get" action="script.php">

    <textarea name="VrsteHolder" rows="4"> </textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Dodaj porudzbinu" name="buttonDodaj" onClick="Inci();"/> 

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: The correct answer is already given, but if you wish to learn more about js scoping, read this: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `var` keyword inside of the `Inci` function.

`var` **redeclares** variables in the current scope, so it will redeclare `broj` every invocation of `Inci`.

This would be the correct way:

```
var broj = 5;  

function Inci(){
   document.frmMain.VrsteHolder.value = ++broj;
}
```

Comment: +1 usually one uses the `var` inside a function for the sake of leaving the outside variables untouched (ex. you have var `hey` outside and need to use the same name in the function without editing the global one)

Comment: ok i did that, but now result in textarea is NaN. Not number 6 as i expected.

Comment: I figure that is right solution, but for me it keep returning NaN. I will try to rework rest of code, thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

because the `var` keyword defines the variable. Remove `var` from your function:

```
function Inci(){
    broj++;
    document.frmMain.VrsteHolder.value = broj;
    }
```

Comment: ok i did that, but now result in textarea is NaN. Not number 6 as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `var` as the other answers detail, redeclaring your variable, or *attempting* to rather, and actually throwing a syntax error because of the combination.

As an aside though that I'm seeing less: don't forget you can increment and get the result immediately by having the ++ ([increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b.2b_%28Increment%29)) *before* the variable, for example:

```
function Inci(){
  document.frmMain.VrsteHolder.value = ++broj;
}
```

[You can test that version out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yvhG8/).

Comment: ok i did that, but now result in textarea is NaN. Not number 6 as i expected.